# What are the figures on the top of the Last Judgement of Hunefer? What is the green furry thing? Why are some but not all holding an ankh?

Tags: ancient-egypt, art, symbols

[image]

I know the first statue represents Ra-Horakhty, the second one is Atum, third is Shu, and the sixth one is probably Sekhmet, but I have no clue what are the rest.

Also, what is the object that is in front of Hunefer on the top left?
[image]
I found a similar thing in the Book of the Dead of Ani, but have no idea what it is.

Finally, why are some statues on the top holding an ankh while others do not?